# How to take some of the properties of an Observable and assign them to another Observable using RxJS operators

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs5, rxjs-observables

I have an employee$ Observable and a personalInformation$ Observable. personalInformation$ is a subset of employee$ and I want to map the matching properties of employee$ to personalInformation$. The observables have many more fields but for simplicity I made them shorter here.

```
export interface EmployeeModel {
  id: number;
  personalEmail: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  remote: boolean;
  office: string;
}
employee$: Observable<EmployeeModel>;
```

Personal Information

```
export interface PersonalInformationModel {
  id: number;
  personalEmail: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}
personalInformation$: Observable<PersonalInformationModel>;
```

This is what I tried but did not work.

```
    this.personalInformation$ = this.employee$
      .pipe(
        map((data) => {
          data!.id,
          data!.personalEmail,
          data!.firstName,
          data!.lastName
        }),
        catchError(err => {
          const message = "Could not load record";
          this.logService.error(message, err)
          return throwError(() => new Error(err));
        })
      );
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: my approach is not working

Comment: did you subscribed to the obervable ?

Comment: what does "not working" mean? do you get an error, or some unexpected data?

Comment: @bubbles I would like to use operators and not have to subscribe to it. I will be subscribing to personalInformation$

Comment: @TmTron Observable<void> is not assignable to Observable<personalInformtion>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With an arrow function, you aren't returning the object correctly. You nee another set of parenthesis around the 'squigly braces `{}`' in your map.

```
this.personalInformation$ = this.employee$
      .pipe(
        map((data) => ({
          id: data!.id,
          personalEmail: data!.personalEmail,
          firstName: data!.firstName,
          lastName: data!.lastName
        })),
        catchError(err => {
          const message = "Could not load record";
          this.logService.error(message, err)
          return throwError(() => new Error(err));
        })
      );
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this helped but it still threw an error. That is because the properties need to be assigned. can you please modify your answer so I can mark it as correct instead of me posting it.
id: data!.id,                  personalEmail: data!.personalEmail, ...